# How to access qemu CLI in github actions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, yocto, qemu

I currently have a yml workflow that runs in Github Actions that will build a Yocto image for qemuarm64. It then will run qemu in Github Actions and I want to pass in arguments to my qemu CLI. However, it seems that I can't get past the login page because my arguments are not passed in properly. Any tips on what might I do wrong?

I tried separating the steps into 3: run qemu, wait 10 seconds, pass in arguments to qemu. However, it seems like it's still passing in arguments to the shell instead to the qemu CLI. This is what my yml file look like. Root is the username and 1234 is the password for the Yocto image

```
- name: Running Qemu
  run: |
    sudo --user user1 --shell << EOF
      # Set bitbake env
      runqemu nographic slirp qemuarm64
    EOF
- name: Wait for qemu to start
  run: sleep 10
- name: Test Qemu
  run: |
    root
    1234
    echo "In qemu"
    poweroff
    echo "Exit qemu"
```

Comment: You'll want to change your `runqemu` script to something that wires up the terminal to a named pipe or other socket you can later connect to. I'm not sure this fits very cleanly in a Stack Overflow question -- what you're asking for is rather a lot of work.

Comment: ...indeed, I'd argue that it might make sense to use a wrapper like libvirt, where you'll have existing tools (`virsh` in that case) to connect to and manage copies of qemu started from that wrapper. If you don't use a wrapper someone else built, then you need to build one yourself; it's doable -- I've done it -- but again, it's arguably more work than anyone can be reasonably expected to do for you _here_.

Comment: You can refer this to get an idea: https://fadeevab.com/how-to-setup-qemu-output-to-console-and-automate-using-shell-script/#3inputoutputthroughanamedpipefile

I think this is what @CharlesDuffy is talking about.

Comment: Do those solutions work for normal QEMU only? Since i've been using runqemu which is a Yocto command, I've seen things work a bit differently Yocto's QEMU? Or is it just me? @GauravPathak